# Will Rust greedily eval a Lazy if it produces a constant value?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization, lazy-evaluation

I am playing with attribute macros by writing one that will obfuscate strings in the source code, and it works great in debug mode, but in release mode, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

My guess is that the compiler sees that the `SyncLazy` will always produce the same value, and during optimizations, it goes ahead and evaluates at compile time, although I don't want this behavior.

I tried wrapping the evaluation in a [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.black_box.html) but the compiler didn't seem to take the hint. I also tried to use the [`optimize_attribute`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54882) feature, though it looks like there isn't an `optimize(none)` available yet.

Example based on the results of `cargo expand`:

```rust
#![feature(once_cell)]
#![feature(bench_black_box)]

use std::hint;
use std::lazy::SyncLazy;

// everything in the lazy was generated by the macro to get the original string back at run-time
static VAL: SyncLazy<String> = SyncLazy::new(|| {
    hint::black_box(String::from_utf8(
        [
            140, 155, 158, 142, 158, 142, 166, 156, 150, 130, 148, 171, 128, 134, 132, 150, 137,
        ]
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, e)| i as u8 ^ !e as u8)
        .collect::<Vec<u8>>(),
    ))
    .unwrap()
});

fn main() {
    println!("{}", *VAL);
}
```

```bash
# expected result:
$ rustc -C opt-level=1 main.rs && if grep 'secret' main; then echo '"secret" is still readable'; else echo "obfuscation worked"; fi
obfuscation worked

# does not hide data:
$ rustc -C opt-level=2 main.rs && if grep 'secret' main; then echo '"secret" is still readable'; else echo "obfuscation worked"; fi
grep: main: binary file matches
"secret" is still readable
```

My workaround is to [set a lower release optimization level](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html) in my `Cargo.toml`, but I'm still curious about what's happening, or if there is a good way to postpone evaluations to runtime. Greedily evaluating a lazy type seems to defeat the purpose of it, so if there's a better explaination of what actually happened, that might help lead to a better solution, too.

Comment: Note that `black_box` doesn't mean "don't optimize the construction of this value," rather it means "pretend you don't know what this value is used for" which prevents things like _fully optimizing away_ the value if it's unused. Note also that the compiler isn't immediately initializing the value -- it's still lazily-initialized -- rather, the compiler is optimizing the function used to lazily-initialize the value, which does not defeat the purpose of lazy initialization at all.

Comment: You could look at how the [obfstr](https://crates.io/crates/obfstr) crate handles this.

Comment: @cdhowie You're saying it would reduce to something like `SyncLazy::new(|| "secret_data_stuff".to_string())`? That seems like it would be a reasonable thing for the compiler to try to do.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows Yes, that is likely exactly what is happening, and probably more than just that -- e.g. the closure is likely inlined into the `SyncLazy` instantiation.

Comment: `black_box` means the compiler has to materialize the input in a register somehow, but it can optimize up to and around that point.  (I'm not sure of the Rust implementation, but it might also make the compiler forget about anything it knows about the value, as if it was a by-reference XOR with a random value, as far as the optimizer is concerned.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is not specific to `SyncLazy`. The compiler can see that iteration over the array and subsequent computation is static, and will "pre-compute" the result as far as possible at compile time as part of its constant folding pass. The exact behavior is not specified, though, as the program can't observe if the compiler did this optimization or not. In general, if the computation is too large or too complex, the compiler will just give up and defer to runtime. Again, as this is not part of the observable program behavior, you can't predict if the compiler does this not at all, in part, or completely. As a rule of thumb, you should expect the compiler to constant-fold if you rely on it not to, and expect it to not constant-fold if you hope it will...

For example, if you compile the following with optimizations enabled...

```rust
pub fn foo() -> Vec<u8> {
    let cypher = [47u8; 15];  // The `encrypted` bytes
    cypher
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(idx, p)| 1 + *p ^ (idx as u8))  // The `decryption`
        .collect()  // The `decrypted` Vec
}
```

... you will see in the generated assembly that the compiler has completely removed the computation and replaced the function with a single allocation, and moved the "decrypted" result directly into the newly allocated `Vec` by means of registers:

```
playground::foo:
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movl    $15, %edi
    movl    $1, %esi
    callq   *__rust_alloc@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB0_1
    movq    %rax, (%rbx)
    movabsq $3978425819141910832, %rcx // This is the `decrypted` result
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)               // as part of the instruction-stream
    movl    $993671480, 8(%rax)  
    movw    $15676, 12(%rax)
    movb    $62, 14(%rax)
    movaps  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, 8(%rbx)
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    popq    %rbx
    retq // No computation in this function at all
```

If we change the length of the array from `15` to `16`, the compiler can't use registers but bakes the "decrypted" bytes into the executable; the result is moved into the newly allocated `Vec` in one fell swoop:

```
playground::foo:
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movl    $16, %edi
    movl    $1, %esi
    callq   *__rust_alloc@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB0_1
    movq    %rax, (%rbx)
    movaps  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0 
    movups  %xmm0, (%rax)
    movaps  .LCPI0_1(%rip), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, 8(%rbx)
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    popq    %rbx
    retq  // Again, no computation
```

If we make the array large enough, the compiler just gives up: It allocates a piece of memory, `memset` it to the value we set in the code (`47` in the example above), and does the whole computation; this is done every single time the function `foo` is called. The point at which the compiler gives up seems to be exactly 609 bytes, which should be considered completely arbitrary and version-specific.

Due to size, I'll not paste the code here...

As it was pointed out in the comment, the `obfstr` implements the behavior you aim for. It has to go through [great pains](https://github.com/CasualX/obfstr/blob/3c06dba7f572078c8035e97c8e57e35755928600/src/bytes.rs#L76) in order to convince LLVM to *not* move the de-obfuscation to compile-time.

As a more general answer to your question: You should never hand secrets to the compiler, and if you do, expect the compiler to leak those secrets to the user. In your case, the obfuscation algorithm is the secret, and the compiler happily leaked it by putting the de-obfuscated bytes into the executable. If you *have* to do this, you'll need to spend the extra work (as the `obfstr` crate does) to "trick" the compiler, and heavily, heavily monitor the result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Yeah, the `obfstr` crate does the same thing, but this was more of a `proc_macro` learning exercise where I just picked something relatively simple to try to implement. I just happened to stumble across some behavior I didn't expect to see :)